# switch case to strategy pattern

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, strategy-pattern

```
Menu.prototype.iconMapping = function (_setroot){
  var case_root = _setroot;
  switch(case_root){
    case "type1":
      // function();
    break;
    case "type2":
     // function();
    break;
    case "type3":
     // function();
    break;
    case "type4":
     // function();
    break;
    case "type5":
     // function();
    break;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this using JS design pattern? Because I hear `switch/case` has a lot of problems. Can you guys give me some advice or show me how it should be done actually? I hear the strategy pattern might be appropriate for this, but I have no clue where to start.

Comment: It largely depends on what you're trying to do, so... a switch by itself doesn't really offer much.

Comment: *"i hear switch case has alot of problem"* For example?

Comment: Evan Trimboli , it was detect the class name and use it to change some css , like if case_root = type 5 , change my background-color.

Comment: Felix Kling i hear it can be modify by oop.

Comment: The real power of swich/case statements takes effect, when there are cases without a break.

Comment: *"it can be modify by oop"* I don't understand what that is suppose to mean. Nothing is wrong with `switch`.

Comment: I'm not sure how the performance is. Should be measured in a test case. It could be compiled as a series of if-conditions. An internal hash map of object properties might be faster. However, it would only be interesting in a loop or heavily called function.

Comment: Why are you introducing a new variable `case_root`, when you could just use `_setroot` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be:

```
var funcs =
{
  'type1': function() { alert('one'  ); },
  'type2': function() { alert('two'  ); },
  'type3': function() { alert('three'); }
};

case_root = 'type2'; //demo
funcs.hasOwnProperty(case_root) && funcs[case_root]();
```

Answer (score -1):

Good article for this pattern in JS here https://dev.to/carlillo/design-patterns---strategy-pattern-in-javascript-2hg3

```
   class StratergyManager {
    constructor() {
        this._strategy= null
    }
    set strategy(strategy){
        this._strategy = strategy;
    }
    get strategy(){
        return this._strategy;
    }
    doAction () {
        this._strategy.doAction();
    }
}

class Stratergy1 {
    doAction () {
        console.log('Stratergy1')
    }
}

class Stratergy2 {
    doAction () {
        console.log('Stratergy2')
    }
}


const stratergyManager = new StratergyManager();
const stratergy1 = new Stratergy1();
const stratergy2 = new Stratergy2();

stratergyManager.strategy = stratergy1;
stratergyManager.doAction();

stratergyManager.strategy = stratergy2;
stratergyManager.doAction();
```